# ios multi-level preferences panes

Tags: iphone, ios

Has anyone been able to to add a second preferences pane to an ios application? I went through the steps, however, the second page I add doesn't keep its settings.

I don't know what I need to add to this question to help clarify.

I changed the "type" of the second .plist to "iPhone Settings plist"; The root item is set correctly to "Preference Items". When I navigate away from the new .plist the type reverts back to "PreferenceSpecifiers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excerpt from [Implementing Application Preferences](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html):

> 1. In the Detail view, select the Root key of the Root.plist file.
> 2. Choose View > Property List Type > iPhone Settings plist.
>
>    This command formats the contents of the property list inside the Detail view. Instead of showing the property list key names and values, Xcode substitutes human-readable strings ... to make it easier for you to understand and edit the file’s contents.

(In Xcode 4.2, right-click the Root key and select Property List Type > iPhone Settings plist.)

You can also try editing the XML directly by right-clicking the file and selecting Open As > Source Code.

Finally, make sure you save the plist after making your changes and before navigating away.

Comment: No matter what I do when I navigate away from my new .plist it changes the root item from "Preference Items" to "PreferenceSpecifiers"

Answer (score 2):

Having the same troubles, resolved by :

- right clicking in the plist editor and checking "Show Raw Keys/Values"
- changing / checking values in raw mode.

Hope that help.